# Json Data is not showing in listview

Tags: android, json

I am learning about Json Parsing I want to show the data in the listview from url
for this i did some code but data in the listview is not showing which is coming from url please tell me what mistakes i am making in the code.

MainActivity Code is

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// URL to get Cities JSON
private static String url = "http://14.140.200.186/Hospital/get_city.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_CITIES = "Cities";
//private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";


// Cities JSONArray
JSONArray Cities = null;

// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> citylist;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    citylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetCities().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetCities extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                Cities = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CITIES);

                // looping through All Cities
                for (int i = 0; i < Cities.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = Cities.getJSONObject(i);

                    //String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);


                    HashMap<String, String> Cities = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    //Cities.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    Cities.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // adding contact to Cities list
                    citylist.add(Cities);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, citylist, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME}, new int[] { R.id.name,});
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Second Class code is

```
public class ServiceHandler {

static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

public ServiceHandler() {

}

/*
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}

/*
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;}
```

And in the activity_main simply i have a listview in LinearLayout
And i have also another layout file list_item with single texview for show showing result..

now please slove my problem

Thanku

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Answer (score 2):

Change From:

```
     private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
```

To

```
   private static final String TAG_NAME = "city_name";
```

It will help now Please check your Service which You are using.

Answer (score 1):

Change From:

```
 private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
```

To

```
 private static final String TAG_NAME = "city_name";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

From

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> citylist;
```

to

```
ArrayList<String> citylist;
```

Your loop should looks like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Cities.length(); i++) {
       JSONObject c = Cities.getJSONObject(i);

        //String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

         // adding contact to Cities list
         citylist.add(name);

 }
```

Pass only ArrayList to adapter.

**Edit 2** :

From

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, citylist, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME}, new int[] { R.id.name,});
```

To

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, citylist);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i changed but now   citylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); and  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, citylist, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME}, new int[] { R.id.name,});   getting red line

Comment: @ArjunSingh, I've edited my answer, please check it.

Comment: i make this change but  mContext is showing red then i initialized it like Context mContext; now app is crashing

Comment: @ArjunSingh, change mContext to MainActivity.this.

Comment: Process: info.androidhive.jsonparsing, PID: 483
                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                              at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)

Comment: i changed mContext to MainActivity.this

Comment: but still getting same problem listview is nothing showing

Comment: @ArjunSingh, I have edited answer again, please check ListAdapter to ArrayAdapter;

Comment: Thanks for help but still getting same problem data is not showing in listview

Comment: there is no error in logcat only one line in logcat is showing after make all the changes as u told me logcat is 02-22 12:20:10.128 4553-4582/info.androidhive.jsonparsing E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)

Comment: @ArjunSingh, run again and post logcat, and make sure you have given internet permission in manifest.

Comment: i run again but now progress dialog is showing after that nothing showing yes i have given internet permission

Comment: @ArjunSingh, please make sure you are not getting any exception.

Comment: sure not getting expception now what can i do

Comment: @ArjunSingh, without logcat, I am sorry

Comment: As i told you logcat is showing only this: 02-22 12:37:35.980 14235-14260/info.androidhive.jsonparsing E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)

Comment: @ArjunSingh, please provide full logcat

Comment: only one line is showing in logcat which  i have pasted already

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of places where things could have gone wrong.

First:

```
} else if (method == GET) {
```

Check if above condition is satisfied. You may want to replace `GET` with `ServiceHandler.GET`.

Second:

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

You need to write code to actually make list adapter visible.

Comment: it is not working for me still i am getting listview blank

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // Dismiss the progress dialog
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
    /**`enter code here`
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, citylist, R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME}, new int[] { R.id.name,});
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Hope it will be help you.